# detect endpoint shutdown when not doing a receive?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

This is a TCP/IP question, been awhile since I have had to do this protocol. A little background information first. We are sending and receiving on different ports. We are using .NET on our side, and the other side is an AS 400 machine.

The issue we are having has to do with when the server closes its receive port and we are still getting successful sends to their port from our client code. The server side (an AS 400 machine) is in a FIN_WAIT_2 state, so never gets the final close from our client (we are continuously calling send, and only doing a reconnect on a write exception). I understand that just because the send on the socket is successful, does not guarantee delivery to endpoint. Is the only way to detect the socket as down by doing a receive on the socket and getting back 0 bytes? We are not doing any receives on this port currently, seems like we are only getting the socket exception on write after their end actually times out awaiting the final close.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what's happening is that the AS/400 is doing a proper TCP/IP shutdown: that is, its sending stream (your receiving stream) is closed, and then it will read from its receiving stream (your sending stream) until you close it. This is the old-fashioned multi-step close handshake that hardly anyone every does anymore, but it is still on the books as the "proper and recommended" way to do it. :)

In particular, FIN_WAIT_2 indicates that the AS/400 has sent a FIN (close) and has received an ACK for that FIN. (The ACK is sent by the OS, so even if you're not reading, they'll at least get the ACK). It is then waiting for a FIN from you, which is never sent.

The purist in me wants to say that you should always have an asynchronous read going, and close the socket when you get EOF (a 0-length read).

Alternatively, if you call `Shutdown` with `SocketShutdown.Receive`, that *might* work but my gut feeling is that it won't. If the AS/400 was sending actual data then it would get a RST back, but if it's just sending a FIN then I think it would just get an ACK even if you shutdown your receive stream, so I don't *think* `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive)` would work.

Comment: The problem with trying to call shutdown on my side (client) is that I don't get anything that says their side has shutdown.  I was just "streaming" messages to their endpoint and dealt with error handing around the NetworkStream.Write(), but I am getting successful writes.  It sounds like I need to have a receive on the socket to know when the server side socket is down?

Comment: As I said, you could try to `Shutdown` your *receive* stream, i.e., immediately after opening the socket, but I don't think that will work. I think you'll have to have an outstanding read to detect when they close.